# MVC4 Dropdown menu for Gender

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, drop-down-menu

I am new to MVC 4, i want to create a drop downmenu for listing the gender.I tried a lot but nothing helped me, also i google it but invain.Please help me in it tha thow to create dropdown menu  for gender please guide me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

say we use an enum for the gender:

```
namespace DropdownExample.Models
{
    public enum GenderType
    {
     Male=1,
     Female=2
    }
}
```

and we make a model like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
namespace DropdownExample.Models
{
    public class ActionModel
    {
        public ActionModel()
        {
            ActionsList = new List<SelectListItem>();
        }
        [Display(Name="Gender")]
        public int ActionId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ActionsList { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

make a controller like so:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DropdownExample.Models;
namespace DropdownExample.Controllers
{
    public class ActionController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ActionModel model = new ActionModel();
            IEnumerable<GenderType> GenderType = Enum.GetValues(typeof(GenderType))
                                                       .Cast<GenderType>();
            model.ActionsList = from action in actionTypes
                                select new SelectListItem
                                {
                                    Text = action.ToString(),
                                    Value = ((int)action).ToString()
                                };
            return View(model);
        }
    }
}
```

then in your view, you use the DropDownListFor html helper you include the following:

```
@model DropdownExample.Models.ActionModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
} 
@Html.LabelFor(model=>model.ActionId)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=>model.ActionId, Model.ActionsList)
```

the DropDownListFor html helper uses at leats these two parameters:

- the name of the property that will hold the selected value
- the `List<SelectListItem>()` that contains all the options in the dropdownlist.

Comment: sir should i put the public enum GenderType
    {
     Male=1,
     Female=2
    }
in my view with the registration form or in model

Comment: greetings! @Johnfranklien the enum can be in the model. in a work enviroment you should place it somewhere it can be reused.

Answer (score 6):

```
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("Gender", new List<SelectListItem>{
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Male", Value="Male"},
        new SelectListItem{ Text="Female", Value="Female"}
        }, "--- Select ---"
        )
    </div>
```

Comment: this is the most clever way since it's just two items

Answer (score 3):

Create a Class for Gender

```
public class Gender
{
    public int ID { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Create a list for Gender anywhere in the Controller

```
 List<Gender> genderList = new List<Gender> {
                                             new Gender{ Name="Male",   ID = 1},
                                             new Gender{ Name="Female", ID = 2}
                                             };
```

You will have to create a SelectList for genders in the Action that will be passed to the view.

```
ViewBag.Genders= new SelectList(genderList,"ID","Name");
```

Finally you'll add a DropDownList to the view

```
@Html.DropDownList("Genders", null, htmlAttributes: new { @id = "genders", @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Gender, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```