# how to add DropDownList to ASP.NET Identity?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I started to use ASP.NET Identity, and my question is how can I add a dropdownlist for gender (Male and Female) to my database?

I added a string value called "Gender" to my "AspNetUsers" table(with migrations in the cmd)

and I want to save there the values from the dropdownlist..

I'm using MVC but I can use Web Forms as well.
I saw this link: [MVC4 Dropdown menu for Gender](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20789968/mvc4-dropdown-menu-for-gender) and I didn't understand how does it connect to the databse.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Controller

```
ViewBag.gender=new List<SelectListItem>(){
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Male", Value="Male"},
    new SelectListItem(){Text="Female", Value="Female"}
} ;
```

In view

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
x => x.GenderId, 
new SelectList(ViewBag.gender as List<SelectListItem>, "Value", "Text"))
```

Comment: ViewBag.gender=db.genders.Select(x=>new SelectListItem()
    {
        Text = x.Name,
        Value = x.Id
    })).ToList();


can you explain where I need to put this code?

Comment: In the controller before `return View()`

Comment: hi, I got an error with this line:
ViewBag.gender=db.genders.Select(x=>new SelectListItem()

the word db is marked in red and I dont know how to fix it.
I use the default Connection.

Comment: Replace db with context object which has gender table

Comment: now I have an error on "genders" ...
Just to be clear - I'm using the default database that I got from the registration to the website..
so now I changed it to "DefaultConnection".genders and I got an error on "genders"

Comment: I have updated controller code, this is easy way when you don't use table Gender in database

Comment: Thanks! now its working.
but I have another question.
I added an another item on the list called "Select Gender"
and I want to know how do I make this dropdownlist a required field to click in the page?